# Haml Hyperlink inside a label tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Inside my .haml file, I have

> = employee.label :tos_confirmation, 'I agree to the Terms of Service.', :class => 'wide'

How do i make Terms of Service a hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is like this:

```
  %label.wide{:for => "tos_confirmation"}
    I agree to the 
    %a{:href => "/tos"} Terms of Service
    and
    = succeed "." do
      %a{:href => "/privacy_policy"} Privacy Policy
```

The only part I'm missing is the "employee" part, which is not too important.

Comment: To help everyone out there, check out this html to haml conversion tool http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
= link_to employee.label(:tos_confirmation, 
                         'I agree to the Terms of Service.', 
                         :class => 'wide'), 
          'http://example.com/tos'
```

Comment: cool, if I just want "Terms of Service" to be a hyperlink and the rest to be just text, how do i do that?